# Compute delta of 2 list of integers

Tags: algorithm

I have 2 maps of : map1 and map2.
where the string is a key, and the value is the number of occurrences of that key.

I want to compare the 'delta' between the maps,i.e. I want to know how far is one table from the other, but I am not sure what is the correct function to calculate that difference.

For example:

map1:
ABBA 100
USA 10

map2:
ABBA 300
USA 210

The difference in occurrences between ABBA in map 1 and 2 is 200, and also the difference in occurrences between USA in map 1 and 2. but it is obviously not the same difference since 10/210 << 100/300.
So it won't help me do an average on the absolute difference.

On the other hand also using division is not right because 0/100 == 0/1000.
I know that I somehow need to combine the 2 methods but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: what do you think about plus one on the count and use division?

Answer (score 1):

If you regard the maps as vectors, in the mathematical sense, then you can compute all the usual distances (metrics), by subtracting matching elements.

Let's say you want the [Manhattan (L1) distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). That's the sum of the absolute differences between matching elements in two vectors:

```
d = 0
for key in map1:
    if key in map2:
        d += abs(map1[key] - map2[key])
    else:
        d += abs(map1[key])  # implicit zero in the other map

for key in map2:
    if key not in map1:
        d += abs(map2[key])
```

Similarly, you can compute the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), which is the square root of the sum of squared differences:

```
d = 0
for key in map1:
    for key in map2:
        d += (map1[key] - map2[key]) ^ 2
    else:
        d += map2[key] ^ 2

for key in map2:
    if key not in map1:
        d += abs(map2[key])

d = sqrt(d)
```

Both of these can be computed in linear time if map lookup is O(1), and so can many other distances.